# Adding a new eav attribute type "file upload"

Tags: attributes, database, eav

I need to have the ability to add a file upload at the admin site and process the files after these have been uploaded. As a first step I like to extend Magento eav attributes with a new custom type "file upload". Therefore I have a number of questions, you may have an answer or can provide me a link for some of these.

Questions

- How to add a new type for an EAV attribute?
- How to add the handling of the field so it gets recognized and rendered as file upload?
- How to setup the persistency handling for this new "type"?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Since you have multiple questions, it is better to ask them in several separate questions, as you will have a higher chance of people answering you.

Answer (score 9):

My examples are geared towards category image attribute, but the principle is the same for product based.

This information should get you going in the right direction (I hope)

Attributes have two elements that define their input and backend (processing) behaviour.

Below is the base requirements for a new attribute created in a category, which is an image. (the snippet is taken from a co-workers megamenu module (with some help from me in some areas, of course ;), and I include the ref to the code to allow you to view the snippet in context, which may clarify the code - [[https://github.com/benjy14/MegaMenu/blob/master/app/code/local/DevBlog/MegaMenu/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php](https://github.com/benjy14/MegaMenu/blob/master/app/code/local/DevBlog/MegaMenu/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php))

```
'megamenu_feature_image' => array(
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Menu Feature Image',
            'note' => 'Make sure the width is 260px',
            'input' => 'image',
            'backend' => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
            'required' => false,
            'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,

        ),
```

The important bits (for you) will be the `input` and `backend` elements.

`'input' => 'image'` relates to : `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image` (all the input element renderers live in `lib/varien/data/form/element`

`'backend' =>` 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image', => relates to (well as it says) `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image` :)

in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Image` you will see a method 'afterSave' where processing takes place after the image is uploaded.

for a custom input renderer, you will rather use 'input_renderer' (ref: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/ I am not sure if 'input' will work for a custom renderer, but worth a try. (magento do change at times)

Thus, you just need to point the attribute to your custom input and backend models.

Hope this helps.