# How to create an image upload product attribute in magento?

Tags: attributes, php

I know to create new product attribute in magento by **catalag->manage attributes**. By the same way i have created an image upload product attribute.It was suceessfully created and also i have added this attribute to default attribute set.

But that image upload attribute doesn't show on product creation page.(Text,Yes/No,etc...I got these kind attributes)

I have searched a lot regarding this issue. I can't find how to reslove this issue. Please save me guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to make it a `Media Image` attributea and add it to the `Images` group in the attribute set. This way the file uploading part is handled automatically by Magento and it also gives you the ability to resize, crop etc etc the image using the `catalog/image` helper.

So let's say your Image attribute is called `awesome_image` you would resize it like this on the frontend

```
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'awesome_image')->resize(150);
```

**[EDIT]** If you do want a new attribute for this. Check out [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2796/adding-a-new-eav-attribute-type-file-upload) on Mage SE. Or optionally, if you don't want to code give [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/file-attributes.html) a try. I've used it once before. It works pretty well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now the image attribute is showing on product management under images group. but i need it to add image for separate group named as product label. can i add image attribute other than image group?

Comment: Check my update ;)